# Excel MATCH function not reading data imported from Access

Tags: excel-formula

I've linked a couple tables from an Access 2010 database into Excel 2010, [result shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHbJE.png).

[image]
In Access, the Fruit field in the People table is a lookup relationship to the Value field in the Fruit table and gets converted to numbers when transferred to excel. I've tried using both `VLOOKUP` and `INDEX` & `MATCH` functions to get the name of the fruit for each person, but it always returns `#N/A`. I tried manually copying the two tables into blank cells and trying the same thing there, and it worked perfectly. I also tried just the `MATCH` portion on it's own with the same result. The linked picture shows the whole thing, but I also have the formula below. How can I use the index saved by the lookup field to get the name of the fruit from the other table, while also maintaining the link to the database?

Formula: `=INDEX(Table_Database4.accdb_1[Value], MATCH(Table_Database4.accdb[@Fruit], Table_Database4.accdb_1[ID]))`

(I'm not actually dealing with fruit, but the example is showing the same problem my actual data has)

Comment: Looking at the alignment of the cells, in the working example the numbers are aligned right in both tables. In the non-working case, the different alignments tell me, that the data types are different, and it can cause the lookup type functions to say there is no match. In the formula try to use conversion from text to number or the other way round.

Comment: I tried setting both columns in excel first to numbers and then to text, but it still showed #N/A for both changes. I also tried `=MATCH(E3, $G$3:$G$7)` on it's own and it returned the same result. In the database, the ID in the fruit table is an AutoNumber (long integer) and the Fruit in the people table is a Number (long integer).

Comment: I just checked, left-aligned numbers are stored as text. Therefore could you try =MATCH(VALUE(E3), $G$3:$G$7)? The VALUE function converst text to numbers.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó that worked! Thank you very much.

Comment: OK, I will add it as an answer, so you can close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, add the VALUE function to convert text to numbers.